# Missing results when using the Identify Tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, identify, nhd

This is my first time using QGIS and I am working on the NHD Plus HR shapefile for the Connecticut River watershed.

Within this, I am trying to use the identity tool to identify the NHDPlusID associated with certain reaches in the watershed; however, when I select a reach, the NHDPlusID does not show up in the identity results.

It showed up initially when I first downloaded QGIS and the shape file but for some reason does not show up anymore. I even tried deleted and re-downloading both the dataset and QGIS but neither has solved this problem. I've attached a screenshot, with the selected reach highlighted in red. The NHDPlusID should show up towards the bottom of the identity results, below SHAPE... and above Enabled. [image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, one of the expected attributes is missing. Does it show up in the attribute table?

Comment: Could you check the Fields tab in the layer properties to see if the NHDPlusID field is present ?

Comment: Hi, thank you both for the comments. I checked both the attributes table and the fields tab and NHDPlusID is not in either. The NHDPlusID did show up when I first started to use QGIS but I'm not sure if the ID was present in the attributes table or the fields tab when I first started. Is there any reason why the ID would show up when I initially first used QGIS vs. not showing up after using QGIS 2-3 days later?

Comment: In your screenshot there is also a non-spatial table which has the same name as the line layer. Maybe that includes your NHDPlusID? If it does, maybe you saw the result of a join between the two.

Comment: Thanks for the thought Cezar. I just checked and it's not there either...

Comment: A link to your data would be helpful so other users can verify or solve your problem

Comment: The link to the dataset is at the end of this comment. The watershed I'm using is number 0108. https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=StagedProducts/Hydrography/NHD/HU4/HighResolution/GDB/

Answer (score 0):

The dataset you are using is NHD, so it will not have the NHDPlusID. You need to download the NHDPlus HR data for that area.